# ExtJs 4 - combobox with jsonstore stays empty

Tags: php, extjs, combobox, jsonstore

I'm trying to load json data to my combo box using jsonStore.
The store is using PHP for retrieving the data from the sever.

I can see that the server is handling the PHP request and response with proper json data, but somehow the combobox stays empty.

Relevant code:

The store and the ComboBox - the ComboBox is inside FormPanel:

```
var groupsStore= new Ext.data.JsonStore({url:'login.php?action=getGroups',
    root: 'entities',
    fields: [{name:'groupName', mapping:'groupName'}]
});

LoginWin = function(cfg) {

this.form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    labelWidth:60, baseCls:'x-plain', autoHeight:true, style:'padding:5px',
    items:[
        {xtype:'combo', name:'groups', fieldLabel:'Group', store:groupsStore, 
displayField:'groupName', valueField:'groupName', emptyText:'Pick group...',    mode:'remote', anchor:'95%', allowBlank:false, enableKeyEvents:true, triggerAction:'all', forceSelection:true
        , listeners:{keypress:{scope:this, fn:function(fld,e){ if(e.getKey()==e.ENTER) doLogin();}}
         }}
    ]
});
```

The json data that returned from the server:

```
{"entities":[{"@type":"webGroup","groupId":"1","groupName":"TEST","groupUsers":
 [{"groupUserId":"2","groupUserName":"FOO","password":"123456"},
 {"groupUserId":"1","groupUserName":"FOO","password":"654321"}],"system":"BLA"},
 {"@type":"webGroup","groupId":"2","groupName":"TESTOS","system":"BLA"}]
,"success":"true"}
```

The PHP code:

```
function getGroups(){
    error_log("API_host: ".$API_host, 0);
    global $API_host;
    error_log("API_host: ".$API_host, 0);

    $url="$API_host/GroupUser/groups";
    error_log("url: ".$url, 0);
    $jsonData = curl_request($url);

    if (!$jsonData) die("{success:false, message:'Connection Error'}");

    echo $jsonData;
}
```

Maybe the data returned from the PHP formatted other than JSON? How can i know it? I'm not sure of anything.

Can't understand why it's not working.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Found the problem.

It was with my php code.

The php file, beside the function 'getGroups',  includes also a html page that loads the formPanel with the comboBox.

So whenever i try to load to store into the comboBox, it loads the entire html with the formPanel and the comboBox from scratch - whichs make my store data to disappear.

When i set the url of the store to other php file that include the same code but without the html block, the store loads it's data correctly and everything is working!

Silly me  :(

Hope it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Their should be **groups** in your json response or change the combo name to **groupName**.

Comment: Can't understand what do you mean. Where should be groups? and change the groupName to what?

Comment: I mean to say that the 'name' config in your combobox is 'groups' which is not their in json response.Actuallty the repsonse is mapped based on the 'name' config of the components when set.

Comment: It didn't help.  I've tried to change the 'name' config to 'groupName' and also to remove it. In both situations, the result is the same, no data in the combo box.  aren't the 'displayField' and the 'valueField' using to do this mapping?

Comment: Nop,and again if comboStore i.e here 'groupsStore', does not have the value which you are trying to set in combo, it won't as you have forceSelection:true.

Comment: It's very odd, since if I use the same comboBox with 'name' config as 'groups' and using just a simple dataStore instead of jsonStore, configuring it's json reader etc. it works fine.  I wonder what's the difference.